# Logistic Regression with Moderation and Control Variable

Tags: r, logistic, interaction, controlling-for-a-variable

I perform a Logistic Regression in R which looks the folllowing:

```
logit <- glm(result~Condition+Strength, data = combined, family = binomial)
```

I am mainly interested in the effect of `Condition` on `result` while controlling for `Strength`. So far the effect is significant. Furthermore I want to include another variable called `Focus` which I expect to be a Moderator for the effect of `Condition` on `result`. Can anyone tell me how to do this, while still controlling for Strength, as without this controlling variable the effect completely disappears?

Comment: Not sure to understand the question. If you want to control for the effect of FOCUS in addition to STRENGTH, simply add FOCUS to your model (result ~ condition + strength + focus). If you find that including FOCUS in the model completely changes the estimates of the other variables, then your predictors might be highly correlated (Check the correlation matrix).

Answer (score 1):

> Can anyone tell me how to do this, while still controlling for Strength

```
logit <- glm(result ~ Condition*Focus + Strength, data = combined, family = binomial)
```

`R` will automatically calculate the main effects of `Condition` and `Focus` for you (assuming that you have set both `as.factor()`), so you don't have to specify the `Condition + Focus` part if you don't want to.

> as without this controlling variable the effect completely disappears?

Do not simply include a covariate because it yields significant results; [this can inflate Type I error and may be considered p-hacking](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/51725721_False-Positive_Psychology) *unless* you have a solid theoretical reason to include the covariate. Including it simply for statistical significance is frowned-upon.

Comment: Is it possible to test and visualise the moderation effect?